# Retrieve array elements from document in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have an endpoint that takes in a route parameter. The forms route takes in the route parameter and uses that parameter to find the corresponding form in the Forms collection using Mongoose. However, when I retrieve the document the "fields" property (which is an array) is returned without any of the elements contained in the array.

the schema for the form collection is as such:

```
const FormSchema = new Schema({
name: String,
fields: [
  {
    name: String,
    label: String,
    type: String,
    validation: { required: Boolean, min: Number, max: Number || null },
  },
],
});

mongoose.model("forms", FormSchema);
```

my endpoint looks like such:

```
app.get("/api/forms/:formName", (req, res) => {
  const formName = req.params.formName;
  Forms.find({name: formName }).then((form) => {
  if (form) {
    return res.send(form);
  }
  return res.send({ error: "No form found" });
  });
});
```

when the response is returned on the front end, the "fields" property is just an empty array even though there are elements in the fields array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

**Schema**

```
const Forms = mongoose.model("forms", FormSchema);
```

add this one in your endpoint file with your own paths

```
const Forms = require('../models/forms');
```

And maybe you can use this as endpoint:

```
app.get('/api/forms/:formName', (req, res, next) => {
    try {
      const formName = req.params.formName;
      const foundForm = await Forms.find({name: formName})

      if (!foundForm) return next(new Error('No form found'));

      res.status(200).json({
        success: true,
        data: foundForm
      });
    } catch (error) {
      next(error);
    }
});
```